# Replacing a XML node

Tags: xml, r

I'm trying to edit a KML file using XML package, replacing a node/child by another.

Basically, I've tried a simple substitution (`doc[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]][[2]]` is a node called 'description', and i'm trying to replace by a node called 'ExtendedData'):

```
doc[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]][[2]] <- do.call(xmlNode, c('ExtendedData', mapply(function(nome, valor) xmlNode('Data', attrs = c(name = nome), xmlNode('value', valor)), paste(tabela[, 1]), paste(tabela[, 2]), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))
```

But didn't work (without any error/warning message. doc[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]][[2]] was unchanged). Next step was try with `removeChildren()`and `addChildren()`:

```
newNode <- removeChildren(addChildren(doc[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]], do.call(xmlNode, c('ExtendedData', mapply(function(nome, valor) xmlNode('Data', attrs = c(name = nome), xmlNode('value', valor)), paste(tabela[, 1]), paste(tabela[, 2]), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))), 'description')
```

This code builds exactally the node I need. But `doc[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]] <- newNode` dosn't works too.

So, any idea of what I can do? I tried make a simple example with the same problem, but I failed (the `<-` operator works well in simple examples), and I can't share the original KML :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replaceNodes` function:

```
library(XML)
myXML <- "<root><a>'hello world'</a></root>"
doc <- xmlParse(myXML)
replaceNodes(doc["//a/text()"][[1]], "test")
> doc
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <a>test</a>
</root>
```

Comment: I tried with `replaceNodes(doc[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]], newNode)`, but says that I cant use with an object with class of `c('XMLNode', 'RXMLAbstractNode', 'XMLAbstractNode', 'oldClass')`. And I'm using xmlTreeParse(), not `xmlParse()` (don't know if it matters)